# Error enviando archivo desde un formulario Access a MySQL usando ODBC

Tags: mysql, ms-access

Tengo una base de datos MySQL que gestiono con phpMyAdmin. En la empresa usan Access y quieren seguir usándolo.

Conecté la base de datos con Access por medio de ODBC, pero cuando intento agregar un archivo PDF me da este error:

> ODBC; falló UPDATE en la tabla vinculada 'archivos jpg'.
>
> [MySQL][ODBC 8.0(W) Driver][mysqld-5.5.5-10.4.14-mariaDB] got a packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet´ bytes (#1153)

Y no sé cómo arreglarlo.

[image: Captura de pantalla del eerror]

Comment: De que tamaño es el archivo?

Comment: El archivo es de 1.5 MB

Comment: Por favor, si sigues con este problema **NO CREES UNA NUEVA PREGUNTA**. Debes editar la pregunta aportando nueva información o bien responder mediante comentarios qué es lo que te falla de la respuesta que te han proporcionado (que, según veo, debería solucionarte el problema).

Comment: lo siento soy nuevo, boy a intentar borrar una de las 2, pero con esta solucion no me genera cambio sigue el mismo error.

Comment: Deberías borrar la otra pregunta, la nueva. Esta solución es válida y si no te funciona deberías investigar el motivo. Creo que no lo estás haciendo correctamente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esta es una limitación definida en la configuración a nivel de MySQL.
Puede que el archivo sea más grande de lo permitido para enviar en la conexión.

Si tienes acceso a la configuración del servidor (se llama `my.cnf` y está localizado en la carpeta de instalación de MySQL, o `my.cnf` si es un sistema basado en Linux) ajusta el valor de esta línea y reinicia el servidor MySQL.

```
[mysqld]
max_allowed_packet=100M
```

O el tamaño necesario para permitir el envío del archivo.

También se puede establecer a nivel de sesión usando comandos `SET`, antes de ejecutar los `UPDATE`:

```
set global net_buffer_length=1000000;
set global max_allowed_packet=1000000000;
```

NOTA: Como son valores globales, esta configuracion dura mientras esté activo MySQL antes de reiniciarlo. Por seguridad podría ser bueno retornar a los valores valores normales debería volver `net_buffer_length` y `max_allowed_packet` a valores por defecto.

Comment: Solo encuentro my.ini pero no el my.cnf

Comment: de hecho ese es, `my.cnf` es para sistemas basados en linux y `my.ini` para windows

Comment: ya hice el cambio pero me sigue dando el mismo error no se si sera por el lado de accces

Comment: tengo instalado en mysql con xamp y abri el arichibo en la carpeta bin. me deja subir imagenes pero al montar un pdf o archivo cualquiera me da ese error

Comment: ¿Dónde hiciste el cambio? ¿Dentro del apartado `[mysqld]`? ¿Comprobaste que se aplicaron los cambios con un `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet'`? ¿Ejecutaste las instrucciones SQL `SET` en phpMyAdmin o en tu conexión ODBC antes del envío del archivo?

Comment: Atendiendo al llamado de atencion borre la ultima pregunta

Comment: ¿este error tiene la posibilidad de estar relacionado con el mime type ?, dado que en phpmyadmin no me da la opcion "Aplicación/pdf" en la tabla de datos

Comment: hice el cambio en [mysqldump]
max_allowed_packet=100M     hay tengo una duda en el archivo me dice lo siguiente   ""You can copy this file to
# D:/xammp/mysql/bin/my.cnf to set global options,
# mysql-data-dir/my.cnf to set server-specific options (in this
# installation this directory is D:/xammp/mysql/data) or
# ~/.my.cnf to set user-specific options.
#"" pero el archivo que edito esta en la carpeta /bin no se si eso pueda ser problema

Comment: Hay dos secciones en `my.ini` relacionadas con max_allowed_packet, haz el cambio en la seccion `[mysqld]`, cambiarlo en `[mysqldump]` no afectará esta parte. (Y no olvidar reiniciar el servidor mysql)

Comment: Correcto. Por eso en la edición que hice de tu respuesta agregué `[mysqld]` a las modificaciones que proponías a `my.ini`. Así quedaba algo más claro. Me alegra saber que se solucionó el problema del OP.